# Capturing full fetch errors

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a fetch request:

```
fetch(url, {

}.then(function(resp))
    // do something
}.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
}
```

My question involves grabbing the entire stack trace of `err`. For example, here is the real error message:

`Access to fetch at 'https://www.google.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Great. This is a usable message. However, `console.log(err)` prints out `TypeError: Failed to fetch`. That's a really useless error message. Is there any way to capture that entire entire message that was logged in console (ie. `var message = //the full error`? `err.stack` does not seem to be a function and `err.message` returns the same useless `Failed to fetch` message

Comment: throw a `console.log(JSON.stringify(resp) );` in the `.then()`, see what it gets back?

Comment: @Snowmonkey nothing showed up

Comment: Do you have this on a repl.it, or a codepen, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Snowmonkey Here ya go https://jsfiddle.net/a490qkvd/

Answer (score 0):

In general, when using `fetch`, you want to make use of the `response.ok` attribute, which is a bit confusing at first. [This](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/) is a really good article on it, and it contains this example which is more or less what you want to do:

```
fetch("http://httpstat.us/500")
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response;
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log("ok");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

That said, you'll still get `TypeError: Failed to fetch` if you end up with a CORS error because they don't give you a nice error code (e.g. 404), they just cancel the HTTP request

Comment: So the implication is that there is no way to access the full error message from Fetch? That seems like a pretty big usability issue

Comment: There is a way to access the full error message from Fetch. It's in my answer. However, that doesn't work for CORS errors because they aren't HTTP errors

Comment: ...And is there a way to access CORS or other network errors?